# wxWebView Page Load Fails with no Internet Connection

Tags: windows, visual-c++, wxwidgets, iwebbrowser2

I am writing a windows application that uses a wxWebView (Trident) to display pages served from an internal server that binds to the localhost interface on an ephemeral port.  I have run into a problem where, if the host computer does not have any active external IP interfaces enabled (such as a laptop in airplane mode), the wxWebView instance refuses to load the page and sends a page load failure event with a string of "INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE".  When this happens, I can make an external browser (including internet explorer) load the page from my web server so I know that the loopback interface(s) are working.  Is there any way to configure the wxWebView instance so that it WILL load the page?

When I try this in the webview sample application, i can see the following in the log window:

```
13:33:33: Navigation request to 'res://ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm#http://www.wxwidgets.org/' (target='')
13:33:33: Title changed; title='http://www.wxwidgets.org/'
13:33:33: Navigation complete; url='http://www.wxwidgets.org/'
13:33:33: Title changed; title='Navigation Canceled'
13:33:33: Document loaded; url='http://www.wxwidgets.org/'
13:34:12: Navigation request to 'http://localhost:57588/stations.html' (target='')
13:34:12: Error; url='http://localhost:57588/stations.html', error='wxWEBVIEW_NAV_ERR_CONNECTION (INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE)'
```

Comment: can you reproduce it the webview sample? Also, what version of the library you are using? What compiler? What OS you test it on?

Comment: @Igor I am using wxWidgets 3.1.0 with Visual Studio 2015.  I am seeing the same behaviour in the sample.  I am testing on windows 10.

Comment: Have you by any chance tried `EVT_WEBVIEW_ERROR` event to redirect to your web server when the error happens.

Comment: @macroland I am processing the error event.  That's how I know the type of error.  Unfortunately, there is nothing to redirect to.  All services in the application are local.  Despite this, the web view refuses to even try to load the page.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein, did you try to debug it? Is failing function something from the WinAPI?

Comment: @Igor Yes, I did try to debug it until it reached the ActiveX invocation on the component.  I didn't see any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching in vain for methods that could be used to configure the iWebBrowser2 instance, I have decided to dump the Trident engine altogether and managed to get wxWebViewChromium to work.  If anyone faces something similar to this, they need to be aware that the current version of wxWebViewChromium do not appear to work with the latest version of CEF.

Answer (score 0):

Note: not an answer, but a comment/question to @Jon Trauntvein, because I don't have enough reputation to comment

I too decided to drop the wxWebView IE engine because it does not render Google Maps polygons.

discussed here, if you want to know

https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=43186

so, I am trying to build a current CEF build

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef

into wxWebViewChromium

https://github.com/sjlamerton/wxWebViewChromium

but this project is 4 years old and the CEF API changed.

Would you care to post here the changes you made to wxWebViewChromium ?
thanks

Comment: I didn't know enough to get wxWebViewChromium to work with the current build of cef.  Instead, I found an older version that is compatible: cef_binary_3.1180.823.